# Move the spaces to the front of the string?

Tags: java, string, data-structures

How can we move all the spaces of the String to the front using Java?

```
Input string  = "move these spaces to beginning"

Output string = "    movethesespacestobeginning"
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Suggestion: Look at the operations provided by the `String` class and see if there are any that would help.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: This [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/4MVNuQ) will do it.

Comment: Use the function trim(),ltrim(),rtrim() for remove the space from both size,left side,or right side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String input = "move these spaces to beginning";
int count = input.length() - input.replace(" ", "").length();
String output = input.replace(" ", "");
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) output = " " + output;
System.out.print(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for speed

```
public static String moveSpacesToFront(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : chars)
        if (ch == ' ')
            sb.append(ch);
    for (char ch : chars)
        if (ch != ' ')
            sb.append(ch);
    return sb.toString();
}
```